How to calculate 'crossing-prefactor' for AQRE
We see that the crossing-prefactor for surface codes in Azure Quantum Resource Estimator is 0.03, and it is cited in this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.0928, however, how is there a formula for this variable more generally?

Crossing prefactor is an input parameter for Azure Quantum Resource Estimator, so the tool doesn't calculate it on the fly. If you look at the AQRE parameters for predefined QEC schemes, different QEC schemes will have a different value used as the crossing prefactor.
The value used as the default value for this parameter is derived empirically from simulation data that is plotted in Fig. 4 in the paper you reference (on the next page after formula (11) that introduces the crossing prefactor). You can see tha the graphs for each distance have the same crossover point. The $y$ coordinate of this point corresponds to the crossing pre-factor. The value used by AQRE is an approximation for all these simulation data plots for any given physical error rate and any code distance.
